# GWT: context menu in RichTextArea

Tags: gwt, richtextbox, contextmenu

I'm using a RichTextArea in a GWT app. I want to add a context menu to my RichTextArea:

```
public class MyRichTextArea extends RichTextArea implements HasContextMenuHandlers {
    public HandlerRegistration addContextMenuHandler(ContextMenuHandler h) {
        return addDomHandler(h, ContextMenuEvent.getType());
    }
}
```

(...)

```
myRichTextArea.addContextMenuHandler(new ContextMenuHandler() {
    public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
        contextMenu.show();
    }
});
```

This works, however, the context menu only appears when I right-click on the border of the RichTextArea. If I right-click into the RichTextArea, e.g. on the contained text, the browser's default context menu is shown.

How can I display my own context menu?

Comment: You probably want to intercept right-mouse clicks to the RichtTextArea's child elements to show the context menu. You can also try to add a mouse handler to the RichTextArea.

Answer (score 1):

Prevent default context memu:

```
myRichTextArea.addDomHandler(new ContextMenuHandler() {

@Override public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
            // do what you want to do instead
}
```

}, ContextMenuEvent.getType());

Comment: Well, this works, but it doesn't prevent the native context menu to show up. So it's no solution to my problem.

Comment: Yes, I found I got the browser context menu too

Answer (score 0):

I would go after a method that tells you that the rich text area has the focus, like hasfocus, or maybe better, an event listener (addFocusListener) to tell you when the focus is there on a mouse click for the right mouse button?

Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, the FocusEvent does not contain any information on how the widget got the focus. That is, I cannot distinguish if it got the focus because of a right or a left mouse click.

Comment: You didn't say you couldn't detect a right-click. You said your code was working on the border only. 

Here is a reference, but I think if you test for event.button==2 or event.button==3, you cover all your bases.

http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html

Anyway, if you check for either button 2 or 3 and it still doesn't work, that's when I would check for focus - after one of those two is clicked. Does that make sense?

Comment: Basically, I'm saying check for left click, then make sure your textarea has focus - then you would know you want to show a context menu, and if you have more than one, you should know which one (like if more than one html element has a context menu).

Anyway, hope that makes sense, and that it helps you.